# color of index in thesis is red

Tags: color, templates, thesis

I really don't know why my index is red. I don't use color in any part of the code.
Someone can help me?I have to finish it by tomorrow!!Thank you very much

The code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}

  \usepackage{packages} % inserisce tutti le macro necessarie per il 
                        % funzionamento

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{caption}


\theoremstyle{plain} 
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}[section] 
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollario} 
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma} 
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposizione} 


\theoremstyle{definition} 
\newtheorem{defn}{Definizione}[chapter] 

\theoremstyle{remark} 
\newtheorem{oss}{Osservazione} 


\usepackage{amsmath}
\algdef{SE}[EVENT]{Event}{EndEvent}[1]{\textbf{upon event}\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}{\algorithmicend\ \textbf{event}}%
\algtext*{EndEvent}
\algdef{SE}[EVENT]{When}{EndWhen}[1]{\textbf{when}\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}{\algorithmicend\ \textbf{when}}%
\algtext*{EndWhen}

\setstretch{1.3}  %interlinea, mettere 1 per singola da usarsi per le bozze!!!

\begin{document}


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definizione}{Definizione}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}


% genera la prima pagina

\titlep

% indica l'inizio della parte introduttiva
\frontmatter
\color{black}
   \input{ringraziamenti}
   \tableofcontents
   \listoffigures
  %\listoftables
%   \listofalgorithms

\clearpage

% indica l'inizio della parte centrale
\mainmatter
      \input{introd} % attenzione! guardare introd.tex per vedere come e' fatto
    \input{cap2}
    \input{cap3}
    \input{cap4}
    \input{cap5}
    \input{cap6}

% da qui in poi \chapter genera un'appendice
%\appendix
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{{\appendixname}\ \thechapter.\hspace{1em}#1}{}}

      %\input{app1}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografia}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

%\cfoot{\emph{Finito di stampare il \today\/ utilizzando \LaTeXe}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: my code compiling in that way.. I just have other files like capthers or introductions in different files..the code I wrote is from the beginning to the end of my file and it works like that

Comment: `\usepackage{packages}` can not work on somebody else's machine, as well as `frontesp`, a package I do not know. Did you mean `frontespizio`? As well, nobody except of you can `\input{introd}` etc. It is very tedious to comment that lines or to create dummy files for those people which want to help you.

Comment: in each "introd" or "chapter" I just write the thesis (no package or other things). To compile is enough to create these files, even if they are empty.I removed the frontespizio part, but the index is still red!

Comment: @user1938352: have a look if somewhere in these unknown (for us) files there is something like `\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}`. With the snippet provided, there are no definitions that makes your table of contents (I suppose you're referring to the table of contents and not index, though in italian they are "indice") red. Likely, you will find this definition in the file `packages.sty` that I'm not aware of.

Comment: in the package packages.sty linkcolor was red.. thank you very much!I really didn't know how to do thank you

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino an answer, sir? :)

Comment: @cmhughes: I really in doubt about its relevance for future visitors. Also, mine wasn't really an answer, but rather a quick look on crystall ball ;) Perhaps community wiki?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino or else too localized- your call :)

Comment: @cmhughes: I wish there still was that closing motivation... tomorrow I will go for cw answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose somewhere in the unknown (for us) files there is something like `\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}`. With the snippet provided, there are no definitions that makes your table of contents (I suppose you're referring to the table of contents and not index, though in italian they are "indice") red. Likely, you will find this definition in the file `packages.sty` that I'm not aware of as CTAN package.